# Rails: form generation based on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, erb

I've got a form to build a `Document`. That form needs adjusting depending on what *type* of `Document` a user has chosen. At this point I've got a deferring kind of method in `new.html.erb` that goes like this:

```
<%= render 'form_'+@template.label.downcase.parameterize.underscore %>
```

Which works fine but it's kinda difficult to manage though because when new types of documents are added I need to create actual HTML files and upload them.

Is there a better way to manage this kind of form generation? A view with hundreds of `if` statements in it feels cumbersome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push it to `document_helper` or `decorator` like :

```
module DocumentHelper
  def form_render
    return 'form_#{type}'
  end
end
```

Comment: Did NOT know about decorators. Good idea!